# Use LaunchControl to run pg_dump in a ruby file

Tags: ruby, macos

Using Mac OSX 10.12.5, I have a ruby file with the following contents

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
Dir.chdir('/Users/my_files') do
  system("pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U MyName development > backup_file.dump")
end
```

it works if I run it from the command line, but if I run it from LaunchControl I get the following error:

```
sh: pg_dump: command not found
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I am not putting the full file path to `pg_dump`.

`pg_dump` is a utility of postgresql which was installed using homebrew. So in my case I did `brew info postgresql` which told me the path to postgresql.  In the bin directory I found `pgdump`.

I also put in the full path to where I wanted `backup_file` saved. This was found by changing to that directory and typing `pwd`.